# Subtracting one single value from a column in a loop gives NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a piece of code that used to work. It goes through a dictionary and subtracts the first value of a column from the values of that column then creates a new column with the difference score. However, today I ran the same code again and instead of the difference scores, now I get a bunch of NaNs. However, I cannot identify what changed , why it worked before and not now (maybe an update?).

I tried three different ways of doing the subtraction, (shown commented on my code) but none of them work, they all get the same NaNs result.

```py
HR_temp = [] 
pp_num = physiodata_dict[f"ICGavg_Predator_1_RESULTS"]['PP_ID'].unique()
for pp in pp_num:
    pp_data = physiodata_dict["ICGavg_Predator_1_RESULTS"][physiodata_dict["ICGavg_Predator_1_RESULTS"]["PP_ID"]==pp][['PP_ID','Epoch','HR']]
#     HR_temp.append(list((pp_data['HR'])-(pp_data['HR'][pp_data['Epoch']==0])))
#     HR_temp.append(list(pp_data['HR'].sub(pp_data['HR'][pp_data['Epoch']==0])))
    HR_temp.append(list(np.subtract(pp_data['HR'], pp_data['HR'][pp_data['Epoch']==0])))
physiodata_dict['ICGavg_Predator_1_RESULTS']['HR_0'] = [item for sublist in HR_temp for item in sublist]a

physiodata_dict["ICGavg_Predator_1_RESULTS"][['HR', 'HR_0', ]][0:10]
```

I expected the output to be:

```
     HR HR_0
0   56.8954 0.0
1   59.7356 2.8402
2   57.0018 0.1064
3   55.8712 -1.0242
4   58.13   1.2346
```

The output is:

```
        HR  HR_0  
0   56.8954 0.0  
1   59.7356 NaN  
2   57.0018 NaN
3   55.8712 NaN
4   58.13   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because Series subtraction is done element-wise, and one of your series only has the one element. All the others get None subtracted from them and produce NaN. You need to get out the first value:

```
HR_temp = [] 
pp_num = physiodata_dict[f"ICGavg_Predator_1_RESULTS"]['PP_ID'].unique()
for pp in pp_num:
    pp_data = physiodata_dict["ICGavg_Predator_1_RESULTS"][physiodata_dict["ICGavg_Predator_1_RESULTS"]["PP_ID"]==pp][['PP_ID','Epoch','HR']]
    HR_temp.append(list(pp_data['HR'] - pp_data['HR'][pp_data['Epoch']==0].values[0]))
physiodata_dict['ICGavg_Predator_1_RESULTS']['HR_0'] = [item for sublist in HR_temp for item in sublist]

physiodata_dict["ICGavg_Predator_1_RESULTS"][['HR', 'HR_0', ]][0:10]
```

But even better would be something like this (note I have simulated your complex data table by adding two different PP_IDs in there, so the final numbers are different from your first example):

```
import pandas as pd

# Do setup
pp_df = pd.DataFrame({'HR':[56.8954,59.7356,57.0018,55.8712,58.13],
                      'Epoch':[0,1,2,0,1],
                      'PP_ID':[0,0,0,1,1]})
physiodata_dict = {"ICGavg_Predator_1_RESULTS":HR_temp}

# the helper
def diff(df):
    df['HR_0'] = df['HR'] - df['HR'].values[0]
    return df

# All the code you need :)
pp_data = physiodata_dict["ICGavg_Predator_1_RESULTS"]
new_pp_data = pp_data.groupby('PP_ID').apply(diff)

print(new_pp_data)

'''
Out:
            HR  Epoch  PP_ID    HR_0
    0  56.8954      0      0  0.0000
    1  59.7356      1      0  2.8402
    2  57.0018      2      0  0.1064
    3  55.8712      0      1  0.0000
    4  58.1300      1      1  2.2588
'''
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that my code and dataframe are actually more complex and very large (there are hundreds of HR values).  As you see on my loop, I first have to select the data that corresponds to a particular participant (PP_ID), and thus, the indexes do not start with 0 always,  which makes it not possible to add the [0] at the end (I tried, it gives an error). If I run the value `pp_data['HR'][pp_data['Epoch']==0]`, it indeed gives me the correct number. But I don't know why it only subtracts it to the first value in the dataframe, instead of to all of them.

Comment: It is because Series subtraction is done element-wise, and one of your series only has the one element. All the others get `None` subtracted from them and produce NaN. I've edited my answer to get you the first value of the `epoch==0` subset that you already do. I simplified your code a bit too.